# socket.io : how to control & check the message flow?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

lets say we have bob and alice:

bob sends a question to alice,if alice gets the question,alice will answer back to bob and if bob gets the answer the commiunication is done!

The scenario:

during `io.to('alice').emit('question');` alice lose her connection and 
disconnected and we use the `disconnect` event and send a notify to bob:
`io.to('bob').emit('hey bob alice is disconnected and she did not received your question);` and bob suddenly disconnect during emitting and reconnect again!
it seems nothing actually transferred between them,right?how could we catch this kind of scenarios on the server?

is there any callback or something exist on socket.io (node.js) to make me sure message transferred to alice or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use acknowledgments by using the second parameter callback:

```
socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) { // emit
  console.log(data); // got callback (ack)
});

socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) { // receive
  fn('woot'); // execute ack callback
});
```

http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)

A more complicated scheme can be created but this is all socket.io supports out of the box.